# Can't build the project in Android Studio

Tags: android

I hope you can help me please.

I downloaded a project of another developer. When I try to build his project, the Android Studio always says "xxxfile.xxx (另一个程序正在使用此文件，进程无法访问。The Chinese sentence means "The file is being used by another program and the progress cannot be accessed.
"). The xxxfile changes every time I build the project.

Comment: Have you tried only building one project and terminating all other programs?

Comment: I tried only build one and terminating other programs, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide more details? If you only have the downloaded project in Android studio, and you build the console will say "The file is being used by another program"? If so, can you say which file it is?

Comment: The file varies......

Comment: Instead of creating a new project, have you tried to import the project?